# How to make Transmission download torrents behind a proxy?

Tags: proxy, bittorrent, transmission

Can anyone help me configure Transmission to download torrent files behind a proxy?

I have `http_proxy` set in my `.bashrc`.

Comment: If you set `http_proxy` in `.bashrc`, transmission will only see it if you run transmission from an interactive bash shell. The right place for environment variables is `~/.pam_environment` or `~/.profile` (for systems that don't use that pam-module). See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DotFiles

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transmission tracker and/or torrent traffic through proxy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63150/transmission-tracker-and-or-torrent-traffic-through-proxy)

Answer (score 9):

Transmission uses the proxy configured using the *Network Proxy* tool located under the *Preferences* menu.

The names can be different in your PC as I am using Ubuntu in Spanish, but the procedure is the same.

Comment: If that is so, then why does it stop downloading torrents the moment I connect the vpn? My network proxy is already set with  a .pac file

Comment: @ubuntuser: I really have no idea, I have almost no experience on this field, I just tested a proxy and remembered how I configured it. Have you tried disconnecting and reconnecting. Note that when connecting through a VPN your address changes. Ohh, you should also check your port configuration, and check if it's open

Comment: i will have a look at the port conf. just curious, which port does a bittorrent file use? isnt it port 80. same for http and torrents?

Comment: @ubuntuser: you can see the port used in Transmission's preferences. Try to open the used port in your VPN's gateway, that might work

Comment: Please note that Proxy Support in Trasmission has been removed as of version `2.12`.

Comment: @MarcoLeogrande what was the reasoning behind this decision?

Comment: @Moonwalker https://trac.transmissionbt.com/ticket/3688 and https://trac.transmissionbt.com/ticket/3817 - From the devs point of view, the proxy support was not good enough, and they also got the impression that "few people use proxies". First they removed the original proxy support, and later they added a feature to use the proxy defined system-wide in the OS. But then the latter feature was doing more harm than good, and the whole thing was removed.