# Transmission tracker and/or torrent traffic through proxy

Tags: proxy, transmission

I am trying to get Transmission to connect through a SOCKv5 proxy.

I am not able to find any settings in the graphical interface to Transmission that allows me to change proxy server for the program.

Is there any other program that could help me tunnel the transmission traffic - for example like Proxifyer for Windows?

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Comment: Yes, I am. But it seems unlikely that I will get any. I am now instead using the overkill solution where I have transmission running on a a virtual box with a VPN on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proxy support in transmission was [removed](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/ticket/3688) some months ago. The best option at the moment seems to use a wrapper library like [torsocks](http://code.google.com/p/torsocks/). You can install it using `apt-get` (or any other method). Now there is a file `torsocks.conf` in `/etc`. Here you enter your server address:

```
server = 192.168.2.7
server_type = 5
server_port = 8080
```

Now you can start transmission with `torsocks transmission` and your traffic will redirected to the SOCKS server.