# How to have transmission in ubuntu 12.04 proxy the tracker requests?

Tags: proxy, bittorrent, transmission, tracker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Transmission tracker and/or torrent traffic through proxy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63150/transmission-tracker-and-or-torrent-traffic-through-proxy)

I cant find any settings in transmission preferences to proxy the tracker requests.I am behind a firewall and they block all known trackers like pirate bay.Is there a way to install an older transmission release that had this option or is there a mirror of piratebay openbittorrent tracker that i can use?

I cant use any other torrent client like ktorrent because i need to use the transmission-rpc.