# How to use proxy for Transmission?

Tags: proxy, transmission

I have heard that Proxy Support in Trasmission has been removed as of version 2.12. Is it possible to use proxy by any other method?

Comment: It's a shame this was closed as it's certainly not a duplicate. The other thread only works for versions prior to 2.12 while this specifically is asking for a solution for later versions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transmission tracker and/or torrent traffic through proxy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63150/transmission-tracker-and-or-torrent-traffic-through-proxy)

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR**: **http_proxy** environment variable works for at least 2.92.
For versions 1.4.x and older see [configuration options here](https://github.com/transmission/transmission/wiki/Editing-Configuration-Files#14x-and-older) or below.

Citation from transmission wiki [page](https://github.com/transmission/transmission/wiki/Environment-Variables):

> Transmission uses the libcurl library for http- and https-based tracker announces and scrapes. Transmission doesn't support proxies, but libcurl itself honors a handful of environment variables to customize its proxy behavior.

relevant variables start here [here](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTPROXY). And in [CURLOPT_PROXY description](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_PROXY.html) there is this:

> libcurl respects the proxy environment variables named **http_proxy**,
>   *ftp_proxy*, *sftp_proxy* etc. If set, libcurl will use the specified
>   proxy for that URL scheme. So for a "FTP://" URL, the ftp_proxy is
>   considered. all_proxy is used if no protocol specific proxy was set.

I run transmission-daemon using systemd, so I just add line

> Environment=http_proxy=http://*proxy_url*:*proxy_port*

to service configuration using

> sudo systemctl edit transmission-daemon.service

and all worked.

I have transmission-daemon 2.92. Can't say for sure for older version, but according to [this wiki page](https://github.com/transmission/transmission/wiki/Editing-Configuration-Files#14x-and-older) you should use this parameters for transmission 1.4.x or older:

> ```
> proxy-authentication String
> proxy-authentication-required: Boolean (default = 0)
> proxy-port: Number (default = 80)
> proxy-server: String
> proxy-server-enabled: Boolean (default = 0)
> proxy-type: Number (0 = HTTP, 1 = SOCKS4, 2 = SOCKS5, default = 0)
> proxy-username: String
> ```

Comment: I've added the line `Environment=http_proxy=socks4h://105.233.32.123:49556` to use SOCKS4 instead of http. There are some [free SOCKS4 websites](https://www.socks-proxy.net/) to get an IP.
You can check your new torrent IP if you [duck-search any service to check your IP](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=check+torrent)

Answer (score 2):

```
vim /lib/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service
```

then add proxy enviroment, like

```
...
[Service]
User=debian-transmission
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:7890" "HTTPS_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:7890" "ALL_PROXY=socks5://127.0.0.1:7891"
Type=notify
...
```

It works on 2.94

Answer (score -5):

Transmission uses the proxy configured using the `Network Proxy` tool located under the `Preferences` menu.

[Reference Solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29832/how-to-make-transmission-download-torrents-behind-a-proxy/29835#29835)

Comment: this is not a solution as the feature was removed as of 2.12, and does not state how to accomplish what's asked (fix and I'll remove my downvote).