# How to use Transmission BitTorrent Client with proxy?

Tags: proxy, transmission

I use Transmission BitTorrent Client v. 2.84 (14307). Could you please help me to find it's proxy settings? That's what I see on it's preferences/network tab:[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think [it was removed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29832/how-to-make-transmission-download-torrents-behind-a-proxy#comment333103_29835) long ago for the issues it had. Probably you should install something else like Deluge

Comment: please make clear that the *proxy feature* was removed